# Internationalization: language list in settings

Tags: android, iphone, internationalization

I translate my app for internationalization, so I'll add in the settings language select option when I noticed that in others applications or simply in the phone settings, languages are translated in the current language. For example, if there is a list of 2 languages (english, french), and if the current selected language is english, so you see : english, french. If the current language is french, you see anglais, français.

I think this is really stupid. Because, when someone try to change the language, he can recognize his own language written in his language, but not necessarily in the current language. In my above example, it easy to guess that french is "français" and english is "anglais". But if the current language is chinese or greek or japanese. it will be hard for a french or an english to set his own language.

Generally, there are more than 2 or 3 languages in the language list. I translated with google a list of 5 languages in chinese (英語，法語，日語，中文，希臘文). So try to find english if you don't know chinese.

In my opinion, regardless of the current language, the language list must be the same. For example, if there are 6 languages (english, french, japonese, chinese, greek, russian) , in any current language we should see (english, français, 日本人, 中國的, ελληνικά,русский). So everybody can recognize his own language.

My question is, is there any reason to continue doing this in that way?

Comment: I believe you're right that you should have 1 list, which is always the same, stating all languages in their own language.
If you'd look at the general language settings of your Android device, you'll see Google does the same.

Comment: I have just seen that on android! great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, there is no reason to keep on doing in this way.